# Net Core App with CefGlue sub-process for Desktop Bridge

Tags: desktop-bridge

A .Net Core app (soon 2.1) with Xilium.CefGlue (.Net bindings for Chromium) sub-processes can be converted using Desktop Bridge for the Windows Store?

Comment: You could just go ahead and try it. Try to convert your current app and if you met actually issues when converting, you could post the details to see if we could help.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT I could try but it requires investment in  resources. If you have experience that Chromium wrappers like CefGlue or CefSharp can't work in Desktop Bridge as they run chromium as subprocess, please tell me, to avoid waste of time and money

Comment: No, we don't have experiences about using Chromium wrappers, but by consulting with my team, it seems like no reason for can't work.